# Buttons disappearing after clicking on them Js/html

Tags: javascript, html

`Hello there, I'm trying to write a counter code in which I have two buttons (Increase and Decrease), I created the functions, and it works but the buttons disappear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Buttons practice</title>
    <script src="/JavaScript/buttons_practice.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="todo-button" onclick="DoneChange()">Changing Text</button>

    <div id="counter">0
        <button id="up">Up</button>
        <button id="down">Down</button>
    </div>

    <div id="counter">0</div>


    
</body>
</html>

    const Counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    const Up = document.getElementById('up');
    const Down = document.getElementById('down');
    let count = 0;


    Up.addEventListener('click', function Increase(){
        count = count + 1;
        UpdateCounter();
        

    });

    Down.addEventListener('click', function Decrease() {
        count = count -1;
        UpdateCounter();

    });

    function UpdateCounter() {
        Counter.innerText= count;
    }
```

I was reading some similar questions, but I couldn't figure it out. Some answers aimed to the InnerText to be the Issue, however I can see this code works, I'm basically using the event listener so I can have Html exclusive to Html, it's modular and better at reading the code I think.

```
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button onclick="countUp()">Up</button>
<button onclick="countDown()">Down</button>
<script>
  let count = 0;

  function countUp() {
    count = count + 1;
    updateCount();
  }

  function countDown() {
    count = count - 1;
    updateCount();
  }
  function updateCount() {
    let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    counter.innerText = count;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. (i.e. include the HTML for the version you are having a problem with). Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons are inside the counter. Consequently, when you rewrite the contents of the counter (with `innerText`) you replace the buttons.

Don’t put the buttons inside the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with id `counter` in this block:

```
<div id="counter">0
    <button id="up">Up</button>
    <button id="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div id="counter">0</div>
```

When you do

```
Counter.innerText= count;
```

you override everything that you have within the first `counter` div that contains buttons, and as a result, they disappear.